# How do I get Build ID of an In progress Pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Am triggering a build Pipeline from a release Pipeline as a **first task** through an API call and that doesn't have any Issue.

**Second Task** - Pipeline needs to wait Until the triggered Pipeline from the **first task** is completed and then go to Third Task. How do i achieve It ?

I have tried below in a powershell task to get the Build ID from the running pipeline and tried to wait through a loop, but am unable to get the Build Id

**First Task to trigger a Build Pipeline**

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://dev.azure.com/Org/project/_apis/build/builds?definitionId-1549&api-version=6.1-preview.6' -H 'Authorization: $(ADO_BASIC_AUTH)' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"definition": {"id": 1549}}'
```

**Second Task as you Suggested**

```
   $B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$(ADO_BASIC_AUTH)"))

$header = @{ Authorization = "Basic $B64Pat" }


$continueCurrent = $true
$uriGetActiveBuilds1 = "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/build/builds?definitions=1549&statusFilter=inProgress,notStarted&api-version=5.1"
    
do
{
    $continueCurrent = $true

    $resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetActiveBuilds1 -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
    

    if ($resultStatus.count -gt 0)
    {
        $continueCurrent = $false
        Write-Host " . "
        Start-Sleep -s 10
    }

}while($continueCurrent -eq $false)

Write-Host "Continue task"
```

The Second keeps waiting even If the Build Pipeline triggered from the First Task is completed

**Output of my Pipeline**

[image: Output with empty Build ID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get Build ID of an In progress Pipeline in Azure DevOps

The idea to solve this request can be:

1. Add a task to get the latest build id of the build pipeline before
   the first task of the release pipeline (triggering a build pipeline)
2. Then get latest Id of the build pipeline again in the second task
   after executing the first task.
3. If it is the same as the previous one, it means that the build
   pipeline has not been running. Wait for 30 seconds.
4. If the ID is different, it means that the newly triggered build
   pipeline has started running. We only need to determine whether the
   status of the latest pipeline is complete

The REST API scripts to get the latest build id before your first task:

```
$connectionToken="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$BuildPipelineUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganization>/<YourProject>/_apis/build/builds?definitions=173&`$top=1&api-version=6.0" 

Write-Host "URL: $BuildPipelineUrl"

$BuildPipelineInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BuildPipelineUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}) 


$LatestBuldId = $BuildPipelineInfo.value.id

Write-Host "LatestBuldId = $LatestBuldId"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OldBuldPipelineId]$LatestBuldId"
```

The REST API scripts to get the latest build id and check the build status after your second task:

```
    $connectionToken = "$(PAT)"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $success = $false
    $count = 0
do{
    try{
    $Secondurl = "https://dev.azure.com/<YourOrganization>/<YourProject>/_apis/build/builds?definitions=173&`$top=1&api-version=6.0"
    $NewBuildPipelineInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Secondurl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
  
    $NewBuildPipelineId = $NewBuildPipelineInfo.value.id

    $NewBuildPipelinestatus = $NewBuildPipelineInfo.value.status

    write-output $NewBuildPipelineId | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

    write-output $NewBuildPipelinestatus | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

    
 
       if($NewBuildPipelineId -eq '$(OldBuldPipelineId)') {           
            Write-output "Wait for new piepine trigger in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30         
      } else {           
            Write-Host "New Pipeline was triggered"
            if($NewBuildPipelinestatus -ne '"completed"') {
            Write-output "wait forpipeline complete,Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30
            }
            else{
            write-output "Pipeline complete"
            $success = $true     
            }     
      }


    }
    catch{
        Write-output "catch - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
        write-output "1"
        Start-sleep -Seconds 30
    }
   
    $count++
   
}until($count -eq 2000 -or $success)
if(-not($success)){exit}
```

The test result:

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Leo Liu-MSFT, I have tried and have the Same problem with both the cases, I don't get the build Id

Comment: Hi @Leo Liu-MSFT, I have tried and have the Same problem with both the cases, I don't get the build Id, It is an empty line - Updated my question with My output.

Comment: Hi @Leo Liu-MSFT the value $LatestBuldId = $BuildPipelineInfo.value.id prints nothing, My Major Issue is this I have tried Many ways to get the Build ID but with no luck

Comment: Hi @Leo Lou-MSFT Also wanted to check to be 100% sure that am not getting the build ID - Is the definitions=173 in the url of your example represent build definition ID ? If so Am just getting an empty line and not build ID

Comment: @saikumarreddy, There is a ` in the url &`$top. Please just copy my scripts to the inline powershell, and replace the organization name, project name and build definition ID. The 173 is the definition ID. And defined the variable PAT with your PAT value. If you still not work with method, please share your scripts in you question and ide personal information.

Comment: @saikumarreddy, I updated a image for the Release pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another way. Add to your release a new variable:

[image]

Then use it in the script to define the build Id and get the status only of the queued build.

Run the build and pass build id:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$teamProject = "<team_project>"
$buildDefId = <build_definition_id>

$body = '{"definition":{"id":<dev_id>}}' -replace "<dev_id>", $buildDefId

$uriRunBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

    
$resultQueue = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriRunBuild -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$buildId = $resultQueue.Id

Write-Host "Build Id: $buildId"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Custom.BuildId]$buildId"
```

Then use the build id to get the build status:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$teamProject = "<team_project>"

$uriGetBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds/$(Custom.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"

$uriGetBuild

$buildStatus = ""
    
do
{
    $buildResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetBuild -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

    $buildStatus = $buildResult.status

    if ($buildStatus -ne "completed")
    {
        Write-Host " . "
        Start-Sleep -s 2
    }

}while($buildStatus -ne "completed")

Write-Host "Continue task"
```

Comment: Hi @Shamrai Aleksander, still unable to get the build ID

Comment: @saikumarreddy just queue a new build with PowerShell (first task) and you`ll get the build ID: `$buildId = $resultQueue.Id`

Comment: Hi @Shamrai Aleksander - I was able to debug the Issue and found out that if I refer Auth token stored in a variable group builds are not getting triggered, So I was not getting the build ID. I have created a new token and tried still the same. But If I add the token in the inline script it works and I can see the build ID and Pipeline is waiting until completion

Answer (score 0):

**One way**

What do you see when you call `Write-Host $result.latestBuild.id`?

**The Other way**

You can add the status filter = `inProgress`

Small example:

First task. Run build:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$teamProject = "<team_project>"
$buildDefId = <build_definition_id>

$body = '{"definition":{"id":<dev_id>}}' -replace "<dev_id>", $buildDefId

$continueCurrent = $true
$uriRunBuild = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

    
$resultQueue = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriRunBuild -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-Host "Build Id" $resultQueue.Id
```

Second task. Wait for build of some build definition

```
$user = ""
$token = "<pat>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>"
$teamProject = "<project>"
$buildDefId = <build_definition_id>

$continueCurrent = $true
$uriGetActiveBuilds = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$buildDefId&statusFilter=inProgress,notStarted&api-version=5.1"

    
do
{
    $continueCurrent = $true

    $resultStatus = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriGetActiveBuilds -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

    #$resultStatus.value

    if ($resultStatus.count -gt 0)
    {
        $continueCurrent = $false
        Write-Host " . "
        Start-Sleep -s 2
    }

}while($continueCurrent -eq $false)

Write-Host "Continue task"
```

Comment: I see Nothing in the logs, it’s an empty line. Let me try this

Comment: Hi @shamrai Aleksander I have tried your solution, the task keeps waiting even if the pipeline triggered is completed

Comment: @saikumarreddy It works in my org. Additionally, you should add `notStarted` status to check not started builds. You can uncomment `$resultStatus.value` to see which builds you see in the request result.

Comment: Does this script exit after the Pipeline triggered from the First task is completed ? And move to the third task ?

Comment: @saikumarreddy you can use it in one or separate tasks. I`ve updated my example to use in two separate tasks in one release.

Comment: I have Updated Question with My First Task to trigger a build Pipeline and Second Task as you suggested, Second task keeps waiting even if the Pipeline triggered in first task is completed